# Storing various data from a text file into an array (and printing it) in C

Tags: c, arrays, printf, scanf

Okay, thanks to everyone who has helped so far, I have managed to fix my original issues for the most part. Now, my output looks perfect except for the  `dSeatPrice`variable. My output is currently printing all zeros for the ticket prices, even though they are clearly different values. Right now I'm using eclipse and cygwin to work on this program, which is updated and shown below. `getFlights()` and `printFlights()` are where the main work is done:

```
FILE *pFileCust;               // stream Input for Customer Reservation data
FILE *pFileFlight;              // stream input for Flight Definitions


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *pszCustomerFileName = NULL;
    char *pszFlightFileName = NULL;

    Flight flightM[MAX_FLIGHTS];
    int flightMentries;
    flightMentries = 0; //may need to delete

    // Process the command switches
    processCommandSwitches(argc, argv,  &pszCustomerFileName, &pszFlightFileName);

    // open the Customer Reservation stream data file
    if (pszCustomerFileName == NULL)
        exitError(ERR_MISSING_SWITCH, "-c");

    pFileCust = fopen(pszCustomerFileName, "r");
    if (pFileCust == NULL)
        exitError(ERR_CUSTOMER_RES_FILENAME, pszCustomerFileName);

    // open the Flight stream data file
    if (pszFlightFileName == NULL)
        exitError(ERR_MISSING_SWITCH, "-f");

    pFileFlight = fopen(pszFlightFileName, "r");
    if (pFileFlight == NULL)
        exitError(ERR_FLIGHT_FILENAME, pszFlightFileName);

    // process the Reservations
    printFlights(flightM, flightMentries);
    getFlights(flightM);
    processReservations(flightM, flightMentries);

    fclose(pFileCust);
    printf("\n");    // included so that you can put a breakpoint on this line

    fclose(pFileFlight);
    printf("\n");    // included so that you can put a breakpoint on this line

    return 0;
}

int getFlights(Flight flightM[]){
    int i;
    i = 0;
    int scanCnt;
    char szInputBuffer[100];
    while (fgets(szInputBuffer, 100, pFileFlight) != NULL){
        scanCnt = sscanf(szInputBuffer, "%10s %3s %3s %10s %4d %[^\n]f\n", flightM[i].szFlightId,
                flightM[i].szFrom,
                flightM[i].szDest,
                flightM[i].szDepartTm,
                &flightM[i].iAvailSeatCnt,
                &flightM[i].dSeatPrice);
        printf("   %10s   %3s  %3s  %5s  %1d    %1f\n",flightM[i].szFlightId, flightM[i].szFrom, flightM[i].szDest, flightM[i].szDepartTm, flightM[i].iAvailSeatCnt, flightM[i].dSeatPrice);
        i++;
    }
    printf("Scanned %d\n", scanCnt);
    return 0;
}

void printFlights(Flight flightM[], int iFlightCnt){
    printf("Original Flight Information\n");
    printf("   Flight Id    From Dest Depart Avail Unit Price\n");
}
```

Also, here is the `typdef struct` for the information I am trying to read in (defined in the h file):

```
typedef struct
{
    char szFlightId[11];                    // Flight Identifier
    char szFrom[4];                         // Origin of the flight
    char szDest[4];                         // Destination of the flight
    char szDepartTm[6];                     // Departure Time (24 hour clock) HH:MM
    int  iAvailSeatCnt;                     // Number of available seats
    double dSeatPrice;                      // Price per seat (i.e., unit price)
} Flight;
```

Finally, here is the first line of input in the text file. There are 8 lines total:

```
H100.15005 SAT HOU 08:00 4 65.00
```

Comment: You stored the return value of `fscanf()`, why don't you check it?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Ok, so I just printed the scan count immediately after the loop and it returned the number 6474728. Something's way off here

Comment: You got your starting point for debugging

Comment: @user3121023 thank you, I had it as %f at first but I got a weird error and changed it. This still doesn't solve the many other random digits and character sequences for the other variables though

Comment: @user3121023 I have tried changing it to sscanf but the output doesn't change at all. Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: @user3121023 ok will do. Also, should I be using fgets() and sscanf() as I am doing right now? Or do I only need one? I have a while loop AND a for loop and I'm not quite sure if that's the right way to do it..

Comment: how did you write it out? that is a struct, it would imply that a `fread` is your friend.

Comment: I have now changed the order of functions in main. The formatting is starting to look a little better and the scan count is now 1. However, the console is still showing nothing but random characters.

Comment: What is the `%[^\n]f` conversion supposed to be?  It is actually reading a string (`%[^\n]`) for a sequence of non-newlines, followed by an `f` which will never be matched since the preceding conversion will only stop when the next character is a newline.  Basically, you've got a type mismatch.  And if you're worried about line-input, don't use `scanf()` or `fscanf()`; they don't care about lines and read across newlines whenever they want to.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok that makes sense.I tried changing it to %1f but that didn't change the data from being all zeros. What should I change it to?

Comment: `%lf` should work for a `double`; `%1f` would look for a single digit `float` — possibly after a sign (though I'd need to double check how signs are handled).  Both cases skip any leading white space; all numeric inputs always skip leading white space.  The difference is digit one (`1`) vs lower-case letter ell (`l`) — for reading a `double`, you need a two letters, `%lf`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've changed the scanner to %lf. Now it doesn't complain about type mismatch. However, it's still printing out all zeros. I've tried changing the print section to %lf and %d as well as to %3.2f to force it to output as a decimal. In every case, it reads in all zeros.

Comment: Have you checked that you get back 6 from `sscanf()`?  If not, then it is reporting that it failed to read 6 items.  Otherwise, it isn't clear where the failure is.  I've not tried compiling, let alone running, the code. Have you printed the input data before parsing it with `sscanf()` to be sure the program is seeing what you expect it to see?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, sscanf() is returning 6. I have it printing out each time I compile it.

Comment: Your code isn't really an MCVE ([MCVE]).  To be an MCVE, you'd remove the `processCommandSwitches()`, for example, and simply force a suitable file name into the variables.  At this stage, the customer info is irrelevant.  You don't need the `printFlights()` function.  Etc.  Basically, we can't copy the code from the question and have it compile and run — whereas an MCVE would allow that.